# Cannot use Kotlin ScriptEngine from Android: Duplicate class

Tags: android, kotlin, scriptengine

I am trying to use generated code from ScriptEngine in Android but I cannot seem to build my project. I have been trying and researching about how to fix this issue, but I cannot seem to get around it. I included the dependencies in a library into my Android Studio project.
This is my library's build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    `java-library`
    id("com.jfrog.bintray") version "1.8.4"
}

val kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"

dependencies {
    implementation (fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion") {
        //exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin")
    }

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion") {
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-build-common")
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-daemon-client")
    }
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:$kotlinVersion") {
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-build-common")
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-daemon-client")
    }
    implementation( "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util:$kotlinVersion") {
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-build-common")
        //exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-daemon-client")
    }
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:$kotlinVersion") {
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-build-common")
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-daemon-client")
    }
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:$kotlinVersion") {
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-build-common")
        exclude("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-daemon-client")
    }
    //implementation(kotlin("script-util", kotlinVersion))
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.14")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3")
    implementation("net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.2.2")
}
```

And this is my app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ignacio.coroutinesamples2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation (project(":scriptparser"))
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Every time I do gradle sync it says "CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL", but when I try to run my project I always get same long message:

```
> Task :scriptparser:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :scriptparser:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :scriptparser:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :scriptparser:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :scriptparser:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :scriptparser:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.BoolPropMapper found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.BoolPropMapper$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.BoolPropMapper$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.BoolPropMapper$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.ClientUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.ClientUtilsKt$makePortFromRunFilenameExtractor$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.ClientUtilsKt$walkDaemons$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.ClientUtilsKt$walkDaemons$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.ClientUtilsKt$walkDaemons$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)

  ... this goes on...

  Duplicate class org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.WallTotalProfiler found in modules jetified-kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-client:1.3.72) and jetified-kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.72)
```

As you can see I tried using "exclude" for some dependencies, but it is not working. I also commented some "exclude", but if I uncomment them build takes much longer and I get this message:
`MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)`

There is probably something I am doing wrong, if you know it please let me know. Thanks in advance.